# Improve performance of dense optical flow analysis (easily)?

Tags: c++, cuda, computer-vision, glsl, opencl

I wrote a program that uses OpenCV's `cvCalcOpticalFlowLK`. It performs fine on a low-resolution webcam input, but I need to run it on a full HD stream with significant other computation following the optical flow analysis for each frame. Processing a 5 minute video scaled down to 1440x810 took 4 hours :( Most of the time is being spent in `cvCalcOpticalFlowLK`.

I've researched improving the speed by adding more raw CPU, but even if I get an 8-core beast, and the speedup is the theoretical ideal (say 8x, since I'm basically only using one of my 2.9GHz cores), I'd only be getting 4FPS. I'd like to reach 30FPS.

More research seems to point to implementing it on the GPU with CUDA, OpenCL, or GLSL(?). I've found some proof-of-concept implementations (eg. http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=189), and many papers saying basically "it's a great application for the GPU, we did it, it was awesome, and no we won't share our code". Needless to say, I haven't gotten any of them to run.

Does anyone know of a GPU-based implementation that would run on Mac with an NVIDIA card? Are there resources that might help me approach writing my own? Are there other dense OF algorithms that might perform better?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the optical flow data coming out is only in two dimensions, are you sure that you are getting better results with a higher-res image? I wouldn't have thought it would make much difference. Maybe you could just scale down the footage even more first, run a comparison with the full res version and check for accuracy - or you could just increase the `winSize` parameter.

Comment: yes, I am scaling down the image used for optical flow analysis. When the resolution gets too low, it misses details in the original image. Ideally, I'd like it to be able to run at full resolution.

Answer (score 1):

What about [OpenVidia Bayesian Optical Flow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvidia/files/CUDA%20Bayesian%20Optical%20Flow/)? Also the paper [Real-Time Dense and Accurate Parallel Optical Flow using CUDA](http://julien.marzat.free.fr/2008_Stage_Ingenieur_INRIA/WSCG09_Marzat_Dumortier_Ducrot.pdf) says that their work is freely available in the CUDA zone. I couldn't find it there immediately, but maybe you will, or can write the authors?

Comment: thanks. Looks like the first is Windows, but may provide a good starting point. The second is one of those papers I mentioned in my first post. Maybe writing the authors will help. Also found this on the OpenVIDIA page, which they say has a LK tutorial in it: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321749642